# What happens when including header with static declarations?

Tags: c, static, inline

For example, let's say I have 2 header files.

**a.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
static __inline foo()
{
    // do something
}
```

Then `a.h` file gets included into `b.h`:

**b.h**

```
#include "a.h"
void bar();
```

With corresponding `b.cpp` file:

**b.c**

```
#include "b.h"
void bar()
{
 foo();
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "b.h"
void main()
{
 bar();
}
```

1. Is `foo()` going to be inlined in `b.c` file?
2. Is `foo()` (static) going to be visible in `main.c` file since it's included via `b.h` file or it will be just visible to `b.c`? (Would guess that it won't be visible since they are not in same translation unit).

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes because they ARE in the same translation unit of `main.c`. Note that code for `foo` will NOT be generated in `main.obj` until you will use `foo` in `main`. If you will than 2 (identical) instances of `foo` code will be generated in both `b.obj` and `main.obj`

Comment: `main.c` includes `a.h` indirectly so `foo` surely is visible

Comment: Hmm alright, in this particular example, what would i need to change so `foo()` won't be visible in `main.c`?

Comment: The `static` function is copy-pasted in the exactly point where you write the `include`, so yes, it's visible

Comment: Include a.h directly into b.c instead of including it into b.h.

Comment: @2501 Oh yeah, I'm so stupid. In that way `main.c` will only see functions included through `b.h` declarations. Thanks!

Comment: @mvidelgauz Please don't use comment section for the answers.

Comment: @user694733 sorry, I don't consider what I wrote as an answer because I don't consider this question as a real question. But it is IMHO of course...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo()` is visible in both `b` and `main`. The compiler sees the files after the preprocessor has done its job.

`main.c` after the preprocessor step:

```
<all the stuff from stdio.h>
static __inline foo()
{
    // do something
}
void bar();
void main()
{
 bar();
}
```

One way to remove `foo()` from `main.c` is to move inclusion of `a.h` from `b.h` to `b.c`:

Modified `b.h`:

```
void bar();
```

Modified `b.c`:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
void bar()
{
 foo();
}
```

Comment: Yep! That's what @2501 said in the comment section. Thank you for your effort though :)

Comment: His comment wasn't there when I started writing my answer... Takes a couple of minutes to fill in all the details.

Comment: One more thing, what if there is a structure in `a.h` and function in `b.h` takes that structure as an argument? In that way i can't make `foo()` invisible to `main.c` since i need to include `a.h` in `b.h` for the function to see that structure reference.

Comment: Normally static stuff is put in a `.c` file. So unless you need it in more places, you should consider moving `foo()` to `b.c`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is `foo()` going to be inlined in `b.c` file?

It is better to say "inlined" into function `bar()`. Probably it is, but not guaranteed. It is a compiler's decision to inline function or not. Marking function as inline is often just a hint, that may be ignored. Refer to your compiler docs to clarify actual behavior.

> Is `foo()` (static) going to be visible in `main.c` file since it's
>   included via `b.h` file or it will be just visible to `b.c`? (Would guess
>   that it won't be visible since they are not in same translation unit).

`foo()` is visible in every translation unit that includes `a.h` directly or indirectly. Assuming inlining was ommited, there is another interesting point: each translation unit defines its own copy of `foo()` i.e. machine code for `foo()` will be generated for each compiled source. It may be wasteful for non-trivial functions since it leads to bloating of generated code. As consequence you should define static functions in headers only if they are small and are intended to be inlined.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought when i encountered `static`. Your binary is just going to be x times bigger.